# Centering buttons horizontally

Tags: button, xhtml, centering

I have searched every where for an answer as to how to align my home, contact etc. buttons centered across the bottom of my xhtml page, I have tried everything I have found but I just can not do it :( I have tried setting up a CSS code, html code everything, nothing works.

Comment: Paste the code that you've tried already so someone may find a possible error in it.

Comment: Can you give us the html code for your buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple setup that allows for the centering of block elements ([demo](http://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/mdJgw)):

#### HTML

```html
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
#footer {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Add this conditionally for less than IE7 inline-block support
ul {
    display: inline;
    zoom: l;
}
/*
```